# Why does water make a paper type substances weak?

Tags: water

Toilet paper, paper towels or cardboard are all relatively strong when dry but as soon as they are wet it is much easier to tear them. Why is this?

Comment: Yes it is. I performed a search for this question before asking but I've never heard of the word "frangible".

Comment: The "frangible" post didn't even come up in the auto-generated list of possible duplicates so I agree with you it isn't as easy to find as it should be. Probably the best way to address the issue is to add/modify some keywords to the text/title of *that* post.